# Convert JSON Object to a LinkedHashMap in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, cxf, jax-rs

Consider the following code.

```
@POST
@Path("records")
public Response insertRecords(List<RecordBean> recordBeans) {
    try {
        List<Record> records = Utils.getRecordsFromRecordBeans(tenantId, recordBeans);
        dataService.insert(records);
        //rest of the Code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle the error
    }
}
```

The `RecordBean` class as follows,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlType(propOrder = {".....", ".....", "values" })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "record")
    public class RecordBean {
    
    ...........

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Map<String, Object> values;

    public void setValues(Map<String, Object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public Object getValue(String name) {
        return this.values.get(name);
    }
}
```

The `insertRecord` method receives a json message and using JAXB/JAX-RS, it will be converted to a `List<RecordBean>` . But a `recordBean` has an attribute called "values". I want this attribute to be converted to a `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` as I want to preserve the order of those values. How can I achieve this? Is there a way to assign a concrete implementation to Map interface through `cxf-servlet.xml` or any other way?

Comment: What JSON provider are you using?

Comment: Hi Jhon, I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.

Comment: Ok, since you're using JAX-B annotations, you'll need to use an `XmlAdapter`.  then use http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxb.html to configure JAX-B

Comment: @Jhon, I managed to fixed the problem, JAX-B binding always preserve the order of elements. The problem was in somewhere else where the inserted data is retrieved. When loading the values from the persistent storage, the values are loaded into a hashmap. So the order is changed.

Comment: @GimanthaBandara I think you can answer your own question :)